# Question about an integrate

Tags: calculus, integration

I can't find a way to solve this:
$$
\int 6 \sqrt{t^4 + 2t^2 + 1}dt
$$
I'm not sure how i have to proceed, can you help me?
I've tried the substitution $u = (t^2 + 1)$, but it got me nowhere.

Comment: $$\sqrt{t^4 + 2t^2 + 1}=t^2+1$$

Comment: $ \ t^4 + 2t^2 + 1 \ = \ (t^2 + 1 )^ 2 \ $ .  You did have a good thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
\int 6 \sqrt{t^4 + 2t^2 + 1}dt = \int 6 \sqrt{(t^2 + 1)^2}dt = \int 6 (t^2+ 1)dt
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\int 6\sqrt{t^4 + 2t^2 + 1}dt=6\int \sqrt{(t^2 + 1)^2}dt=6\int t^2+1 dt=6(\frac{t^3}{3}+t)+C$

Answer (score 0):

$\because 6\sqrt{t^4+2t^2+1} = 6\sqrt{(t^2+1)^2} = 6\;|t^2+1|$

$\therefore \int 6\sqrt{t^4+2t^2+1} \operatorname{d} t = 6\;|\frac{t^3}3+t|+c_0$